# Greater than / Less than date/time table expression

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the following expression in a MS-access table:

`IIf([End Date/Time]>="12/8/2016 6:00:00",1,0)`

`12/08/2016 18:15:00` will return a '1', however 
`12/08/2016 14:23:29` returns a '0'

I'm assuming this is an issue with AM/PM.  I tried putting '6:00:00 AM' in my expression but no change.

Also I would like to replace '12/8/2016' with 'yesterday' but `date()-1` doesn't seem to be working.

EDIT: I figured out that the time needs to be '06:00:00'.  That yield the correct dates.   Still don't know how to get this automatically (ie yesterday at 06:00)

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

2 things. First, I believe you need to convert your string to a datetime. I think think you're getting wonky results because it's trying to compare them as a different format. Like a strings or numbers. To format as a date time you use a format fucntion:

```
Format("12/8/2016 6:00:00AM", "mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss am/pm")
```

Second, to add a date you need the DateAdd function.

```
DATEADD('d',-1,"12/8/2016 6:00:00AM")
```

'd' defines the -1 as a 'day' being added.

So, putting it all together:

```
DATEADD("d",-1,Format("12/8/2016 6:00:00AM", "mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss am/pm"))
```

And finally, if you want the want the rolling yesterday, and not perpetually 12/7/2016 (since you would just use that date if it was the case), you need to get today's date with this function:

```
Date()
```

So, throwing this into our mix we get:

```
DATEADD("d",-1,Format(DATE() & " 6:00:00AM", "mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss am/pm"))
```

Comment: Thanks, it won't let me use the DATEADD function in expression builder but I should be able to do this in VBA

Comment: You've got this mixed up. _Format_ does what its name implies, formats a date value. Thus it always returns a string, not a date value. So in `Format("12/8/2016 6:00:00AM", "mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss am/pm")` `"12/8/2016 6:00:00AM"` is first casted to a date value using your settings in Windows, then `Format` returns a formatted string, which again is casted to a date value before `DateAdd` can handle it. Quite convoluted.

Comment: @Gustov You're right. My answer felt too complicated, but it worked, so I just rolled with it. Thanks for the explanation. +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that you threat dates as strings. Use *date* always, no exceptions.

Further, if your field is not a date value, you must convert it.

Thus, this will work:

```
IIf(DateValue([End Date/Time]) >= #2016/12/8 6:00:00#, 1, 0)
```

and this:

```
IIf(DateValue([End Date/Time]) >= Date() - 1, 1, 0)
```

and this:

```
IIf(DateValue([End Date/Time]) >= DateAdd("d", -1, #2016/12/8 6:00:00#), 1, 0)
```